# Errors When Running an app on iOS 10 Beta 1 Device

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to run an app on my iOS 10 Beta 1 device using Xcode 8 and it is throwing two errors:

1. `Signing for Bolts requires a development team. Select a development team in the Target Editor.`
2. `Code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'`

I can't seem to find anything online about these problems. This app worked fine with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.3. All of my certificates in Keychain are valid. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid it is beta side effect issue.

Comment: I had a feeling. Are you having that same problem? @EvgenyKarkan

Comment: No, I am not big fan of Xcode beta. What you can try is to select Bolts framework target, go to build settings and try to set Dont code sign.

Comment: I don't blame you! Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set team as MyTeam and provision profile "Automatic"

Comment: I assume this will work for some and not others, thanks for the response!

Comment: Maybe you have to set team and provision for CocoaPods frameworks?